# Проблема линковки программы с библиотекой

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, компоновщик, wxwidgets

Пытаюсь запустить программу под Linux(Linux Mint). При запуске ELF выводит следующую информацию об ошибке:

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and wxCore used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
```

Написано что программа и версия библиотеки не совместимы, хотя тут же пишут что и там и там версия 2.8.

Вывод ldd если передать ему исполняемый файл

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7c6b3000)
libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f4f60dae000)
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 (0x00007f4f60a5c000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f4f60724000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f4f602e1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4f5ff58000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4f5fd40000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f5f94f000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5f30d000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5f058000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5ee34000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5ebe7000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5e993000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5e67c000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f4f5e479000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f4f5e273000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f4f5e06b000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f4f5de46000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f4f5dbde000)
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f4f5d967000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f5d5c9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f5d3aa000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4f5d18d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f5cf89000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f4f5cd61000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f6138f000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5cb5d000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5c950000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f4f5c74a000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5c524000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f4f5c207000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5be68000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f5bc52000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f4f5ba0d000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f4f5b803000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f4f5b5f3000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f4f5b3e8000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f4f5b1de000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f4f5afdb000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f4f5add8000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f4f5abc6000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f4f5a9bd000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f4f5a7b5000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4f5a543000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f4f5a328000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f4f5a121000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f4f59efb000)
libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f4f59ced000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f4f59ae9000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f4f598e3000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f4f5962f000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f4f5938a000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f4f59158000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f4f58f55000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f4f58d48000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4f58b40000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f4f58918000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f4f586fd000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f4f584a9000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f4f5820b000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f4f57fd9000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f4f57dd2000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f4f57bbd000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f4f57970000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f4f57743000)
```

По сути, судя по ошибке, разница только в ABI версии(?). Я так понял, что C++ ABI это стандарт, который описывает, как реализован язык на уровне двоичных кодов(вызовы функций, где и как хранятся данные и т.д.). Можно ли как-то поправить эту проблему? И если нет, то получается нужно перекомпилировать библиотеку libwxgtk с компилятором по стандарту C++ ABI 1002? Доступа к исходникам программы у меня нет.

Comment: Вообще-то вам следует запускать это программу на поддерживаемой ей системе. Даже у максимально самодостаточных программ, которые статически линкуют все сторонние библиотеки переносимость относительно слабая.

Comment: Разными же компиляторами строились, вот там числа разные видите?

Comment: А если доступа к исходникам нет, то чего вообще время на это тратить? Если это за деньги купленный продукт, то вам в техподдержку.

Comment: @0andriy техподдержка молчит(

Comment: @user7860670 вообщем-то я и пытаюсь запускать на той системе, которая указана в документации)

Comment: Ну если вы в этом уверены, то стоит попробовать запустить программу на свежеустановленной системе, а то мало ли, вдруг вы там какой-нить sudo make install навояли.